# Can I connect to the ethernet wall socket directly

Tags: networking, windows-10, router

EDIT: How would I test my routers speed without getting a new one ? I do not believe (simply instinct) that my connection is slow due to it, but it is a possibility .

Many of my friends are able to connect to the internet through the Ethernet wall socket .

When I connect a brand new Ethernet cable (I've tried a few) to my laptop and the wall socket, nothing happens. - windows 7 and windows 10

The internet for devices connected wirelessly to my modem cuts off however :(

I am trying to connect to the internet via the wall socket to check if my modem is slowing down my connection

I am on an adsl2+ connection

Thanks

Comment: how do we know what your wall socket is connected to?

Comment: Have you tried connecting your laptop via ethernet to other sources?

Comment: Contact the person or group that provides internet service via your wall sockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test the internet speed of an individual PC or connection by connecting to http://speedtest.org (via browser) as an example. This will give you speed figures for downloads and uploads. At least you can compare these to values at your friend's location.

For a wired internet connection you can probably not use a cable directly to that socket. IF this socket provides the ADSL connection (speculative) you need a modem or router to convert from ADSL to ethernet first.

You seem to already have one on premises as you have access to WiFi which is an additional feature of many ADSL routers. If that is the case, find that router and connect your notebook directly to it with a cable (routers always have ethernet sockets or ports) and measure the througput in comparison to throughput if connected via WiFi. You'll see if the WiFi is the limiting factor or the connection itself then.

Answer (score 0):

Your wall socket is probably not connected to a router or a modem. If you want to use it, find the cable that goes into it an plug it into your modem's Ethernet port. The wall socket is not actually a magic Internet source. It is just a continuation of a cable that must be connected somewhere to work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was wondering how I would test if my interenet speed is bad specifically because of my router.